# VBA to copy into a new workbook and save

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I hope you can help. I have code below. Essentially what it does is, it opens a dialog box that allows a user to select an excel sheet, then it goes out to the country column (11) filters it, then copies and paste that country into a new worksheet names the new worksheet after that country then repeats the action for the next country.

What I want it to do now is instead of creating a new sheet and naming it. I want it to create a new workbook for each country, copying and pasting the information, and then saving and naming the new workbook to a folder.

My Code is below.

Any help is as always greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

    MsgBox "Pick your TOV file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName


Call Filter '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

End If


End Sub

Public Sub Filter()
    Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

    With Worksheets("CountryList") '<--| refer to data worksheet
        With .UsedRange
            Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
        End With

        With .Range("A1:Y" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(11).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 6th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 11, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
                    ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't complete but I think you want something along these lines, add a wokbook variable:

```
'Add this above the loop    
Dim wb As Workbook

'Replace where you create a new sheet with something similar to this
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
wb.SaveAs Filename:=rCountry.Value2
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Unfortunately I am getting a compile error 'Cant assign to read-only property' Is there away to correct this? The error is happening here `wb.Name = "Country Name"`

Comment: Apologies, you need to Save the workbook to change its name. So replace that line with: `wb.SaveAs Filename:="Country Name"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is greatly appreciated. Its working but unfortunately "Country Name" cannot be used to save every workbook. I need the code to save every workbook after the name in the country column so Belgium will save as workbook Belgium and Bulgaria as Workbook Bulgaria and so on until the country column is empty.

Comment: Sorry I thought you might change that, based on what you have above I think this will work: `wb.SaveAs Filename:= rCountry.Value2`

Comment: Boo Yaaah!! That is perfect. Thank you so so much. You have some real Excel skills my friend. Much respect from Dublin. :-)